# perceptron for OR function doesnt converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I am implementing a simple perceptron for classifying OR function in python. however the error doesn't converse. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
def activation_function(x):
    if x<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

training_set = [((0, 0), 0), ((0, 1), 1), ((1, 0), 1), ((1, 1), 1)]

w = random.rand(2)
errors = [] 
eta = .2
n = 100

for i in range(n):
    for x, y in training_set:
        u = sum(x*w)        
        error = y - activation_function(u)       
        errors.append(error) 

        for index, value in enumerate(x):
            w[index] += eta * error * value

ylim([-1,1]) 
plot(errors)
```

Error plot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you are missing the bias b...

If you add it it converges beautifully.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py

np.random.seed(42)
w = np.random.rand(2)
b = 0
errors = [] 
eta = .2
n = 10

for i in range(n):
    for x, y in training_set:
        u = np.sum(x*w)+b     
        error = y - activation_function(u)       
        errors.append(error) 

        for index, value in enumerate(x):
            #print(index, " ", value)
            w[index] += eta * error * value
            b += eta*error
```

Note that I imported the library differently than you with some more reasonable name, so that I know where which function come from... Let me know if that helps you...

And by the way this is the result of the classification. I hope the colors make sense... REd and blue are kind of flashy but you get the idea. Note that you can find infinite solutions to this problem. So if you change the random seed you will get a different line that will linearly separate your points.

[image]

Additionally your algorithm does not converge since when you have your line passing through (0,0), although your prediction is wrong, the weights will not be updated since `value=0` for this particular point. So the problem is that your update will not do anything. That is the reason of the oscillations of your error.

**EDIT** as requested I wrote a small tutorial (a Jupyter notebook) with some example on how to draw the decision boundary of a classifier. You can find it on github

github repository: https://github.com/michelucci/python-Utils

Hope it is useful.

**EDIT 2**: And if you want the quick and very dirty version (the one I used for the plot in red and blue) here is the code

```
lim = 3.0
X1 = [x1 for x1 in np.arange(-lim,lim,0.1)]
X2 = [x2 for x2 in np.arange(-lim,lim,0.1)]
XX = [(x1,x2) for x1 in np.arange(-lim,lim,0.1) for x2 in np.arange(-lim,lim,0.1)]
Xcolor = ["blue" if np.sum(w[0]*x1+w[1]*x2)+b > 0  else "red" for x1 in X1 for x2 in X2]
x,y = zip(*XX)
py.scatter(x,y, c = Xcolor)
py.scatter(0,0, c = "black")
py.scatter(1,0, c = "white")
py.scatter(0,1, c = "white")
py.scatter(1,1, c = "white")
py.show()
```

Comment: Could you please post here the code for the decision boundary? Thank you so much for your excellent explanation!

Comment: Hi I wrote a tutorial on how to draw the decision boundary. Enjoy :) Let me know if it helps you.